# My Password Protected Pages Aren't Working

Tags: pages, password

I have a home page that includes images with links to three other pages. Each of these three pages is password protected, (I used the same password for each.) Now when I or anyone else clicks on the image, the password prompt page does come up. However, after putting in the password, one of two things happen. -In some browsers, it just reloads the password prompt page. In others, you're sent to a completely blank page. I've asked the support team of like, literally every aspect of the site (theme, plugins, everybody) for help. The only support team to get back to me in the last three days suggested that I increase the wp-memory limit. Only when I went to do that, it was already at the level they suggested. I'm really frustrated at this point. I tried to work around the problem by making a separate site for these pages and password protecting the separate site with a plugin that can password protect your entire site - however for some reason the links to the password protected site from my public site caused the password protection not to work at all. I've broken my site and rebuilt it six ways from Sunday trying to figure out the problem. I'd really appreciate any insight into this problem.

Comment: What type of password protection do you use? The native WP password protected posts?

Comment: This thread has some answers:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/password-protected-pages-not-working-5/page/3/